# PostgreSQL ALTER command - Permission Denied - Environment Question

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to run a single line PostgreSQL command to alter a users password. I've got an error that I can't seem to find a solution for anywhere.

```
root@linux:~# sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'myc00lpassword';"
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
```

I read that the permission denied error is because the postgres user doesn't have any permissions on the directory /root (coz I'm running this command as root).

Makes sense.

So how can I modify the command so that when I sudo, it takes on the environment for postgres?

I have tried:

```
root@linux:~# sudo su - postgres psql -c "ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'myc00lpassword';"
psql: ALTER: command not found

and

root@linux:~# su - postgres psql -c "ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'myc00lpassword';"
psql: ALTER: command not found
```